# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication3.exe

Tags: c#

I'm using C# to develop a windows forms application and I required to store certain values (Ex: UserID and Role), in order to use them again in various forms throughout the application.
The User ID and the Role will be changed with each login.

So tried using static classes.

To test it out first, I did the following.

Created "Form1" with a textbox and a button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            common.text = textBox1.Text;

            Form2 obj = new Form2();
            obj.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then created "Form 2" with only a label.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = common.text;

        }
    }
}
```

And to interconnect these two forms, created the following class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{

    public static class common
    {

        public static string text            
        {
            get
            {
                return text;
            }
            set
            {
                text = value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The purpose was to see if the label text on form2 would change when clicked on the button after entering text into the textbox in form1.

When running the code, the following error was thrown. Displays that this is thrown from the "set" method of the class.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication3.exe
```

If anyone could provide any clarity on this, it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your set method is calling itself.
You need to add private string and change it and then return the changes via get.

Try this:

```
private static string _text;

public static string text            
        {
            get
            {
                return _text;
            }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
            }

        }
```